# ** Error: (vlog-13069) D:/CCSIT/DMSD/traffic_light_controller.v(2): near "traffic_light_controller": syntax error, unexpected IDENTIFIER

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

There is some problem with my code, but I can't find it.

```
entity traffic_light_tb is
end traffic_light_tb;

    component traffic_light_controller is
        Port ( clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
               rst : in  STD_LOGIC;
               tl_out : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0));
    end component;
```

Comment: You appear to have posted a near-duplicate. [\*\* Error: D:/CCSIT/DMSD/traffic\_light\_controller.v(2): (vlog-13205) Syntax error found in the scope following 'entity'. Is there a missing '::'?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/648995/error-d-ccsit-dmsd-traffic-light-controller-v2-vlog-13205-syntax-error)

Answer (score -1):

You have multiple problems:

1. You are using a Verilog compiler to compile VHDL
2. `component` declarations need to be inside an `architecture`.